# Need to create comma separated list for each instance of value in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a 2 column table with 2 IDs, each pair being unique. I would love to find a way to create a comma separated list for each instance of the first column, IE:

```
IDcolumn1value1 | IDColumn2value1, IDColumn2Value2, IDColumn2Value3; IDcolumn1value2 | IDcolumn2Value2, IDcolumn2Value4
```

I could create a cursor, and iterate over every single item in IDcolum1, but given that there are ~8k pairs, that might not be most efficient.

Currently I have:

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' , '') + Component_Softpaq.SoftpaqNumber
FROM         Softpaq_SKU INNER JOIN
    ComponentVersion ON Softpaq_SKU.ComponentVersionID = ComponentVersion.ComponentVersionID INNER JOIN
    ComponentPass ON ComponentVersion.ComponentVersionID = ComponentPass.ComponentVersionID INNER JOIN
    Component_Softpaq ON ComponentPass.ComponentPassID = Component_Softpaq.ComponentPassID
group by Softpaq_SKU.SKUID, Component_Softpaq.SoftpaqNumber

SELECT @listStr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FOR XML PATH to generate a comma delimited list without cursors. [Check out this article](http://blog.namwarrizvi.com/?p=140)